# ARM Templates - Multiple Linked Templates in a master template not allowed

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

We are trying to create an ARM template using linked templates. So i started with vnet and subnet and created 2 different linked templates. Now i tried to create a master.json and master.parameters.json . The parameters file has the values for name and address space of network and one subnet.
Now, in the master template i tried to use 2 linked templates and the release in azure devops is failing with the following error:
Deployment template validation failed: 'The resource 'Microsoft.Resources/deployments/LinkedTemplate' at line '37' and column '5' is defined multiple times in a template. 
Task failed while creating or updating the template deployment.

networkSubnetTest.json

```
"{
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {
    "vnetName": {
        "type": "string",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "Name of the Virtual Network"
        }
    },
    "vnetAddressPrefix": {
        "type": "string",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "The IP Address pool for the virtual network in CIDR format."
            }
    },
    "subnetPrefix": {
        "type": "string",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "The IP Address pool for the Subnet in CIDR format."
        }
    },
      "subnetName": {
        "type": "string",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "Name of the Subnet"
        }
    }
},

"variables": {
"templateBaseUrl": "https://github.com/something/",
"virtualNetworkTemplateUrl": "[concat(variables('templateBaseUrl'), 'VirtualNetwork.json')]",
"subnetTemplateUrl": "[concat(variables('templateBaseUrl'), 'Subnet.json')]",
"parametersUrl": "[concat(variables('templateBaseUrl'), 'networksubnetnsgtest.parameters.json')]"
},

"resources": [
{
   "apiVersion": "2017-05-10",
   "name": "LinkedTemplate",
   "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
   "properties": {
     "mode": "Incremental",
     "templateLink": {
        "uri":"[parameters('virtualNetworkTemplateUrl')]"
     },
     "parameters": {
      "uri":"[parameters('parametersUrl')]"
      }
   }
},
{
  "apiVersion": "2017-05-10",
  "name": "LinkedTemplate",
  "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
  "properties": {
    "mode": "Incremental",
    "templateLink": {
       "uri":"[parameters('subnetTemplateUrl')]"
    },
    "parameters": {
      "uri":"[parameters('parametersUrl')]"
     },
     "dependsOn": [
      "LinkedTemplate",
      "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks', parameters('vnetName'))]"
     ]
    }
},
],

"outputs": {
    "returnedVnetName": {
        "type": "string",
        "value": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks', parameters('vnetName'))]"
    },
    "returnedVnetAddressPrefix": {
        "type": "string",
        "value": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks', parameters('vnetAddressPrefix'))]"
    }
  }
}
```

The question here is is it not possible to have one master template and have multiple linked templates? I am aware of having one giant template with everything written in it but we dont want it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my version of the ARM template that works. The template `name` values definitely need to be different during simultaneous deployment. As shown in the deployments record, there are three deployments created by the one master template.

I made three noted changes plus others to handle the URIs. See diff output at bottom.

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "vnetName": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Name of the Virtual Network"
      }
    },
    "vnetAddressPrefix": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The IP Address pool for the virtual network in CIDR format."
      }
    },
    "subnetPrefix": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The IP Address pool for the Subnet in CIDR format."
      }
    },
    "subnetName": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Name of the Subnet"
      }
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "templateBaseUrl": "[deployment().properties.templateLink.uri]",
    "virtualNetworkTemplateUrl": "[uri(variables('templateBaseUrl'), 'VirtualNetwork.json')]",
    "subnetTemplateUrl": "[uri(variables('templateBaseUrl'), 'Subnet.json')]",
    "parametersUrl": "[uri(variables('templateBaseUrl'), 'networksubnetnsgtest.parameters.json')]"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "apiVersion": "2017-05-10",
      "name": "VnetDeployment",
      "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
      "properties": {
        "mode": "Incremental",
        "templateLink": {
          "uri": "[variables('virtualNetworkTemplateUrl')]"
        },
        "parameters": {
          "uri": {
            "value": "[variables('parametersUrl')]"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "apiVersion": "2017-05-10",
      "name": "SubnetDeployment",
      "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
      "properties": {
        "mode": "Incremental",
        "templateLink": {
          "uri": "[variables('subnetTemplateUrl')]"
        },
        "parameters": {
          "uri": {
            "value": "[variables('parametersUrl')]"
          }
        }
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "VnetDeployment"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "outputs": {
    "returnedVnetName": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks', parameters('vnetName'))]"
    },
    "returnedVnetAddressPrefix": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks', parameters('vnetAddressPrefix'))]"
    }
  }
}
```

Diff Output
[image]

Parts of the PowerShell used to execute:

```
$templateUri = 'https://<storageAccountName>.blob.core.windows.net/<containerName>/Lab/Master-Fixed.json'
$parameters = @{ 'vnetName' = 'myvnet'; 'vnetAddressPrefix' = '10.0.0.0/16'; 'subnetPrefix' = '10.0.0.0/24'; 'subnetName' = 'mysubnet'; }
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name "brstring-20190124" -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -TemplateUri $templateUri @parameters
```

Comment: thank you, one last thing, in the azure devops project i added the rawgithub url to the template and parameters. I used https://raw.githubusercontent.com/something/master/networksubnetnsgtest.json   When i use your variable referencing i am getting an error, what did you use in Azure Devops as your base template url and parameters url?

Comment: Here is the PowerShell with some parts or URI redacted.

    $templateUri = 'https://<storageAccountName>.blob.core.windows.net/<containerName>/Lab/Master-Fixed.json'
    $parameters = @{ 'vnetName' = 'myvnet'; 'vnetAddressPrefix' = '10.0.0.0/16'; 'subnetPrefix' = '10.0.0.0/24'; 'subnetName' = 'mysubnet'; }
    New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name "brstring-20190124" -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -TemplateUri $templateUri @parameters

Comment: thank you, one last thing, in the azure devops project, i used linked artifact for template location and parameters.  When i use your variable referencing which you suggested i am getting an error, Deployment template validation failed: 'The template variable 'templateBaseUrl' is not valid: The language expression property 'templateLink' doesn't exist, what did you use in Azure Devops as your base template url and parameters url? Please help me with this last referencing part.

Comment: I need to host all my code on Azure Repos eventually now using github, so this way the storage account will not help me, i need an approach from a Repository perspective rather than a storage account

Comment: I moved the files to GitHub and used the corresponding URI at [https://github.com/brianstringfellow/StackOverflowExercises/tree/master/AzureRM_Templates/54355229](https://github.com/brianstringfellow/StackOverflowExercises/tree/master/AzureRM_Templates/54355229). It should be available and work for you. **NOTE** - I used storage accounts to simulate deploying the VNet and Subnet resources because they're easy. :)  The actual URI `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/brianstringfellow/StackOverflowExercises/master/AzureRM_Templates/54355229/Master-Fixed.json`

Comment: works like a dream, used most of your inputs and changed a few, thanks a lothttps://github.com/rangerlynch7/AzDevopsTest Github link for anyone who might read this in the future.

Answer (score 0):

names of the deployments have to be different (because it wouldnt be able to tell one from another if they are the same). so just call them something like template1, template2, template3. or by the function - what they do. like deployVnet, deployVm, etc.

Comment: Nope that is not working, linked template is the unique identifier, i tried to call it vnet temp, subnet temp instead of linkedTemplate at both places and got a syntax error.

Comment: what? you joking or something? i give you the right answer and you accept the same answer and claim mine is wrong?

Comment: my apologies i had some errors in my code. your idea worked